# Grouping rows in a DataTable by column, then summing the contents of other columns in that group

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable in C# that looks something like this:

```
name | amount | other columns...
--------------------------------
  x  |   10   |
  x  |   20   |
  y  |   42   |
  y  |    1   |
  y  |   23   |
```

And I'd like to write a method that returns something like this:

```
name | total
-------------
  x  |  30
  y  |  66
```

More details on request:

I'm getting the DataTable from the GetData query in the table below in a DataSet, what I need is the rows grouped by product(string) and the sum of productAmount(int).
[image]

Efficiency isn't really a concern, could anyone help?

Further edit: In case it's relevant, I'm changing the DataTable to a DataView then applying a RowFilter based on the datePlaced column and then doing DataView.toTable() to get it back again before I want this query to run.

Comment: Give us some code of your table and we will see.

Comment: Added what context I could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your datatable name is `ordersDT`

```
ordersDT.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
   .GroupBy(product => product["name"])
   .Select(grouped => new {
      name = grouped.Key,
      total = grouped.Sum(product => (int)product["amount"])
   });
```

---

I've created a sample with your data, and runned it:

[image: debugging]

Comment: What does dbContext represent here?

Comment: @EdwardDuffy Sorry, actually missread datatable with entityframeworks.... Gonna fix that in a second

Comment: Fixed and tested.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: How do you do this when you don't know ahead of time how many columns there'll be or what their names are?

Comment: @RobotHead somehow you should know beforehand which columns should be grouped. If you don't know the name ahead of time, you could keep it's name as an argument then call it after some user interaction. (btw, that's an 5+ year old answer)

Comment: For some reason, 2018 only seems like a couple of years ago.